# How can I open a file/folder when I click a button?

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a Screen Share tool for my Minecraft server and I want you to be able to click a button that will open an application like \program.exe and another button opens a directory like %appdata%.minecraft

How can I open a file/folder when I click a button?

Here is my code that you could edit as an example:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Minenow {

    private JFrame frmMinenow;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void NewScreen() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Minenow window = new Minenow();
                    window.frmMinenow.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
     public Minenow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmMinenow = new JFrame();
        frmMinenow.setTitle("Minenow");
        frmMinenow.setBounds(100, 100, 793, 503);
        frmMinenow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frmMinenow.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton(".minecraft");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(58, 50, 161, 80);
        frmMinenow.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }
`}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? There is no actual question in this post.

Answer (score 2):

> I want for you to be able to click a button and it will open an application like \program.exe and another button open a directory like %appdata%.minecraft

You can use the `Desktop` class to open external applications.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate With the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more information and working examples.

If you want to read a text file into your application then you can read the file into a text area. The tutorial link from above also has a section on `How to Use Text Areas`. You can just use the `read(...)` method of the JTextArea to read load the data.

Answer (score 0):

By using JFileChooser you can easily open a FileDialog (if that's what you mean). Take a look [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/show-simple-open-file-dialog-using-jfilechooser), there should also be a way to specify which fokder needs to be opened.